# Example of $\kappa$-closed but not $\kappa$-directed closed poset

Tags: set-theory, forcing

A poset $(\mathbb{P}, <)$ is $\kappa$-closed iff every descending sequence of length $<\kappa$ has a lower bound. $(\mathbb{P},<)$ is $\kappa$-directed closed iff every directed subset of size $<\kappa$ has a lower bound. If $\mathbb{P}$ is $\kappa$-directed closed, then it is $\kappa$-closed. I remember reading that the converse does not hold. What would be an example to show that?

Comment: If my memory serves me right, Kurepa trees.

Comment: See Exercises $2.10,2.11$, and $2.13$ in [this PDF](https://www.math.uci.edu/~mzeman/M285-11/fe-02-120126.pdf).